# Override template member in Interface

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to declare some type of base class with template methods which i can override in derived classes? Following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

class Base
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    std::string method() { return "Base"; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    std::string method() override { return "Derived"; }
};

int main()
{
    Base *b = new Derived();
    std::cout << b->method<bool>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect `Derived` as the output but it is `Base`. I assume it is necessary to make a templated wrapper class which receives the implementing class as the template parameter. But i want to make sure.

Comment: One basic problem I see at the first glance: your code is lacking `virtual`

Comment: You cannot define a virtual template method.

Comment: `override` only works for virtual methods, and you can only override methods with the same signature. `method<bool>()` is not the same as `method<int>()`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1) Your functions, in order to be polymorphic, should be marked with **virtual**

2) Templated functions are instantiated at the POI and can't be virtual (what is the signature??How many vtable entries do you reserve?). **Templated functions are a compile-time mechanism, virtual functions a runtime one**.

Some possible solutions involve:

- Change design (recommended)
- Follow another approach e.g. multimethod by Andrei Alexandrescu (http://www.icodeguru.com/CPP/ModernCppDesign/0201704315_ch11.html)

Comment: So some kind of wrapping is the only solution?

Comment: What do you mean with changing the design? Are there some common patterns for this?

Comment: What I mean is that templates are a compile-time construct, if you need run-time type identification and then compile-time type identification you're likely doing something wrong because of mixing the two concepts

Answer (score 6):

Template methods cannot be virtual. One solution is to use static polymorphism to simulate the behavior of "template virtual" methods:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

template<typename D>
class Base
{
    template<typename T>
    std::string _method() { return "Base"; }
public:

    template<typename T>
    std::string method()
    {
       return static_cast<D&>(*this).template _method<T>();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
    friend class Base<Derived>;

    template<typename T>
    std::string _method() { return "Derived"; }
public:
    //...
};

int main()
{
    Base<Derived> *b = new Derived();
    std::cout << b->method<bool>() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

where `method` is the interface and `_method` is the implementation. To simulate a pure virtual method, `_method` would absent from `Base`.

Unfortunately, this way `Base` changes to `Base<Derived>` so you can no longer e.g. have a container of `Base*`.

Also note that for a `const` method, `static_cast<D&>` changes to `static_cast<const D&>`. Similarly, for an rvalue-reference (`&&`) method, it changes to `static_cast<D&&>`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible aproach to make your example work as you expect is to use `std::function`:

```
class Base {
  public:
    Base() {
      virtualFunction = [] () -> string { return {"Base"}; };
    }
    template <class T> string do_smth() { return virtualFunction(); }
    function<string()> virtualFunction;
};
class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    Derived() {
      virtualFunction = [] () -> string { return {"Derived"}; };
    }
};

int main() {
  auto ptr = unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived);
  cout << ptr->do_smth<bool>() << endl;
}
```

This outputs "Derived". I'm not sure that this is what you realy want, but I hope it will help you..

Comment: Interesting idea. Wouldn't use if it there is another way (which in this case is) but will keep in mind. Thank you.

Comment: This might have potential, but the example does not do anything with the type T, which is the whole point of a function template. It would be nice to demonstrate how this technique could enable a derived class to override do_smth using an argument with a different type T.

Comment: I think I made this work by adding a parameter of type T to do_smth and then saving the argument value to a class member variable named m_t before calling virtualFunction, whose lambda closure [&] then captures the value of m_t. The type of m_t is a base class, and each lambda expression can use static_cast to cast it to a particular derived class type.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I actually came up with a working solution. The best way to show the solution is by an example:

**What we want**(doesn't work, since you can't have virtual templates):

```
class Base
{
    template <class T>
    virtual T func(T a, T b) {};
}

class Derived
{
    template <class T>
    T func(T a, T b) { return a + b; };
}

int main()
{
    Base* obj = new Derived();
    std::cout << obj->func(1, 2) << obj->func(std::string("Hello"), std::string("World")) << obj->func(0.2, 0.1);
    return 0;
}
```

**The solution**(prints `3HelloWorld0.3`):

```
class BaseType
{
public:
    virtual BaseType* add(BaseType* b) { return {}; };
};

template <class T>
class Type : public BaseType
{
public:
    Type(T t) : value(t) {};
    BaseType* add(BaseType* b)
    {
        Type<T>* a = new Type<T>(value + ((Type<T>*)b)->value);
        return a;
    };

    T getValue() { return value; };
private:
    T value;
};

class Base
{
public:
    virtual BaseType* function(BaseType* a, BaseType* b) { return {}; };
    template <class T>
    T func(T a, T b)
    {
        BaseType* argA = new Type<T>(a);
        BaseType* argB = new Type<T>(b);
        BaseType* value = this->function(argA, argB);
        T result = ((Type<T>*)value)->getValue();
        delete argA;
        delete argB;
        delete value;
        return result;
    };
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    BaseType* function(BaseType* a, BaseType* b)
    {
        return a->add(b);
    };
};

int main()
{
    Base* obj = new Derived();
    std::cout << obj->func(1, 2) << obj->func(std::string("Hello"), std::string("World")) << obj->func(0.2, 0.1);
    return 0;
}
```

We use the `BaseType` class to represent any datatype or class you would usually use in a template. The members(and possibly operators) you would use in a template are described here with the virtual tag. Note that the pointers are necessary in order to get the polymorphism to work.

`Type` is a template class that extends `Derived`. This actually represents a specific type, for example `Type<int>`. This class is very important, since it allows us to convert any type into the `BaseType`. The definition of the members we described described in `BaseType` are implemented here.

`function` is the function we want to override. Instead of using a real template we use pointers to `BaseType` to represent a typename. The actual template function is in the `Base` class defined as `func`. It basically just calls `function` and converts `T` to `Type<T>`. If we now extend from `Base` and override `function`, the new overridden function gets called for the derived class.