# How to override a templated function from non-templated parent class

Tags: c++, templates

Supposed I have a base class with a templated member function:

```
class Base {
 public:
  template <typename T>
  void Loop(T* input) {
    InnerLoop(input);
  }

 protected:
  template <typename T>
  void InnerLoop(T* input) {...}
};
```

I want to have a child class that implements the `InnerLoop` function, but it gives me a linker error

```
class Child : public Base {
  void InnerLoop(ConcreteType* input) {...}
};
```

Any way to make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override template member in Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422845/override-template-member-in-interface)

Comment: Looks like you actually should get rid of `Child` and simply specialize `Base::InnerLoop`

Comment: @D-RAJ great find, but I'm too unclear on what this question's really about to hammer the question shut. Might be a better answer than "Just don't do that." once the asker clarifies their intent.

Comment: Also: Always include the error message in the question _as-is_.  Just stating "_gives me a linker error_" isn't helpful. (I don't get a linker error for this code - but it doesn't `override` `InnerLoop` either since that can only be done with `virtual` methods as mentioned in the link @D-RAJ shared)

Comment: Perhaps you want something like CRTP [example](https://godbolt.org/z/jWbv6E)?